# MySQL Multiple Select, Multiple Where Clauses

Tags: mysql, select

Instead of running hundreds of SELECT queries for one operation, I want to just run one big query, which I'm hoping will ease the load on my server.

```
SELECT (
(SELECT link_type_id FROM connections WHERE (node_to_id = '0' AND node_from_id = '1') OR (node_from_id = '1' AND node_to_id = '0')),
(SELECT link_type_id FROM connections WHERE (node_to_id = '0' AND node_from_id = '2') OR (node_from_id = '2' AND node_to_id = '0'))
)
```

There will be many more SELECTS in this query, but even the two aren't working.  When I run this code I get the error:

```
Operand should contain 1 column(s).
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: You need to use `UNION SELECT` and lose the outer `SELECT`, it won't really be that much more efficient though.

Comment: what is your criteria for selection? `(node_to_id = '0' AND node_from_id = '1') OR (node_from_id = '1' AND node_to_id = '0') `doesnt seem to differ.. both options are the same

Comment: @doublesharp it's less about efficiency, more that I want to reduce the number of time I query the database.

Comment: That's what I meant, a UNION is a separate query with it's own execution plan even as part of a larger query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try below may be but you may need `UNION`

```
SELECT link_type_id FROM connections 
WHERE (node_to_id = '0' AND node_from_id = '1') 
OR (node_from_id = '1' AND node_to_id = '0')
UNION
SELECT link_type_id FROM connections 
WHERE (node_to_id = '0' AND node_from_id = '2') 
OR (node_from_id = '2' AND node_to_id = '0')
```

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by the parentheses outside of the columns.  Even something as simple as:

```
SELECT ((SELECT 1), (SELECT 1))
```

Will yield this error -- the problem is that MySQL can only display one column per ... well ... column, and the entire `()` wraps a single column.  If you remove the outer parentheses it will display each `SELECT` in a separate column.