# Python: append to mysql command depending on list length prior to execution?

Tags: python, mysql

I want to append conditional clauses to a mysql command prior to execution that will vary based on the number of elements I want to pull from the DB.

For example, I have a massive list of genes and for each gene of interest I have the coordinates of all of the exons.

**Gene_ID exon start end**

geneA exon1 325 359

geneA exon2 554 601

geneB exon1 870 900

geneB exon2 990 1010

geneB exon3 1200 1350

As you can see geneA has 2 exons and geneB has three exons. I want to execute a command such as the following to return a count of all elements from the DB within the exons coordinates.

```
select count(*) from db_x where position between exon1_start and exon1_end and position between exon2_start and exon2_end;
```

Because of the different number of exons in each gene (some genes can contain tens of exons), I need to append an additional "and position  between exon_end and exon_start" conditional statement for each and every exon before the execution of the overall command.

I'm struggling to come up with a logical solution to this. At the moment for each gene, I'm passing a list of concatenated start_end positions to a function that then queries the mysql server.  eg for geneA ['325..359','554..601']

The command I'm using (after setting the cursor up) is as follows;

```
cur.execute('select count(*) from db_x where position between '+str(exon1_start)+' and '+str(exon1_end)+' and position between +'str(exon2_start)+' and '+str(exon2_end))
```

This would be fine if it was just 1 or two exons, but how can I deal with potentially very long lists of exons? How can I dynamically reformat the command before executing?

Would really appreciate some help as I'm stumped!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could dynamically build a dictionary which stores exons data and build sql queries based on such dictionary:

```
gene_exons_dict = dict()


def add_exon_to_gene(gene_name,gene_exon):
    if gene_name not in gene_exons_dict:
        gene_exons_dict[gene_name] = []

    tmp_exons_dict = {'start': gene_exon[0], 'end': gene_exon[1]}
    gene_exons_dict[gene_name].append(tmp_exons_dict)


def get_sql_query_for_gene(gene_name):
    if gene_name not in gene_exons_dict:
        raise Exception("exons not defined for gene: %s" % gene_name)

    sql_query = 'select count(*) from db_x.tb_y WHERE '
    exons_count = len(gene_exons_dict[gene_name])
    for exon_data in gene_exons_dict[gene_name]:
        sql_query += '(position >'+str(exon_data['start'])+' AND position <'+str(exon_data['end'])+')'
        if exons_count > 1:
            sql_query += ' AND '   # change it to OR if query should return sum of sets instead of their intersection

    # removing last and for multi-exons case
    if exons_count > 1:
        sql_query=sql_query[:-5]

    return sql_query

if __name__ == '__main__':

    add_exon_to_gene('gene1', [1, 2])
    add_exon_to_gene('gene1', [3, 8])
    add_exon_to_gene('gene1', [10, 15])

    add_exon_to_gene('gene2', [20, 25])

    print get_sql_query_for_gene('gene1')
    print get_sql_query_for_gene('gene2')
```

which gives output:

```
C:\tmp>python dynamicDictTest.py
select count(*) from db_x.tb_y WHERE (position >1 AND position <2) AND (position >3 AND position <8) AND (position >10 AND position <15)
select count(*) from db_x.tb_y WHERE (position >20 AND position <25)
```

Comment: The sql syntax won't work for me even on mysql cmd line. I can query with "select count(*) from db_x where position between 1 and 2", but adding the additional "and where position between 3 and 8 and where position between 10 and 15" raises a syntax error.

Comment: ok, I haven't validated the query. just implemented described behavior to match your example. depending on your needs you should join "between" parts with OR or AND operators. look here and modify the query accordingly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893090/mysql-multiple-select-multiple-where-clauses and of course the "between" part should be modified to proper WHERE statement.

Comment: I updated the code but still the whole set of conditions after WHERE may need to be put in brackets. It's also unclear if you need a sum or intersection of sets so change the AND to OR in sql_query += ' AND ' and if you do so also change  sql_query=sql_query[:-5] as to sql_query=sql_query[:-4] as OR is one letter shorter.

Comment: you were also missing table name required by WHERE. I checked on a real MySQL DB the query works. Not sure what else could I do to help you. conditions in the example above do not intersect so the result will be empty but if you use OR operator you will get a sum of sets defined by each (position > X AND position < Y)